# Requests. __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need your help.

I get this error using requests.get():

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
```

I found only one piece of advice online which is to update the requests library, but it did not change anything.
Python 3.9, Requests 2.27.1.

```
print(requests.__version__)
2.27.1
```

Here is a code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=###########'
r = requests.get(url)
```

Here is a Traceback

```
r = requests.get(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\OLEG~1.KAZ\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13156/3951091591.py", line 1, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 335, in request

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 438, in send
    auth = request.auth

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 282, in send
    response.url = req.url

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 423, in urlopen

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 238, in _get_conn

  File "C:\Users\oleg.kazanskyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 560, in _new_conn

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
```

Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Post the code that raises the error.

Comment: Hello,
I modified the question and I added a code to it.
I have changed only an API key.

Comment: Post the entire error message including traceback.

Comment: I've just added a Traceback.

Comment: See https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5959

Comment: Thanks, @deceze, it helped. But only if I remove xmla library. But I still need it for another project, is this the only way?

Comment: What is your `urllib3` version?

Comment: Hello, @9769953, print(urllib3.__version__)
1.26.6

Comment: @deceze, I reinstalled xmla and requests libraries again and now it magically works!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, @deceze, for the piece of advice.

I removed the XMLA and Requests libraries and reinstalled both as it's described here:
[github.com/psf/requests/issues/5959](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5959)

Now it works.

For whatever reason, I did it twice to make it work.